# I can't insert data into database from a form symfony2 doctrine

Tags: database, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, controller

*I cant find data in my database when I submit the form and i got no error , I need your help*

I can't insert data into database symfony2 doctrine
if you noticed an error please mention it 
// this is my contact action

```
  public function contactUsAction() { // contact action
        $contact = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($contact);
                $em->flush();
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', 'Votre message a été bien envoyé');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('carRentalMainBundle:Main:contactUs.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

// And this is my view 
this is my view 

{% extends 'carRentalMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}


    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Contactez-nous</h3>
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('Notice') %}
    <ul><li class="alert-success">
    {{flashMessage}}
        </li></ul>
{% endfor%}
    <br/>
    <form  method="POST" action="{{path('car_rental_main_contact')}}" {{form_enctype(form)}} >
        <div class='form-group'>
{{form_errors(form.name)}}
{{form_label(form.name,' Nom :')}}
 {{form_widget(form.name)}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
{{form_errors(form.email)}}
{{form_label(form.email,' Email :')}}
 {{form_widget(form.email)}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
{{form_errors(form.subject)}}
{{form_label(form.subject,' Sujet :')}}
        </div>
 {{form_widget(form.subject)}}
        <div class='form-group'>
{{form_errors(form.content)}}
{{form_label(form.content,'Message :')}}
 {{form_widget(form.content)}}
        </div>           

{{form_rest(form)}}
        <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" value="Envoyer" >
    </form>
    </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please show us your ContactType code

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give a little advice if version of Symfony you use >=2.3 you can use `$form->handleRequest($request)` to reduce code. More information about it you can get from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) ...

About you problem, you can set`{{form_errors(form)}}` in you template, as described above. Or get error report in you controller by `$form->getErrorsAsString()` for example.

Code Example:

```
public function contactUsAction(Request $request) { // contact action
        $contact = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            // if need to catch database flush exceptions 
            try
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($contact);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', 'Votre message a été bien envoyé');
            } catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $this->render('carRentalMainBundle:Main:contactUs.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                     // for debug only
                    'form_errors_list' => $form->getErrorsAsString(),
        ));
    }
```

and in your template you can set (only for debug proccess):

```
<pre>{{dump(form_errors_list)}}</pre>
```

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Is there flashMessage after submit? If no, then add {{form_errors(form)}} to see form errors.